# Listeners são uma implementação de Observer?

Tags: java, design-pattern, listener, observer-pattern

Estou tentando entender o conceito de Observer e sua implementação, e acabei encontrando este exemplo onde é usado *listeners* ao invés das classes `observable` e `observer`:

[image: Diagrama Observer]

Este gráfico foi retirado [deste link](http://www.dsc.ufcg.edu.br/~jacques/cursos/map/html/arqu/observer.htm), onde é explicado uma forma alternativa de implementar o mesmo conceito em java, porém, usando as classes `EventObject` e `EventListener`, do pacote `java.util`.

*Listeners* são a base do Swing/AWT, e reparando a forma que as ações dos componentes gráficos são monitoradas, junto com o exemplo acima, notei certa semelhança com o padrão Observer.

A implementação usando Listeners (como no exemplo acima e no Swing) seria uma forma de aplicação do padrão Observer?

Há alguma diferença de aplicabilidade entre esta forma e com o uso as classes `Observable`/`Observer`?

`Listeners` aumentam o acoplamento em comparação com `Observable`/`Observer`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sim, é o mesmo. Se prestar bem atenção, os nomes são um pouco diferentes, mas a função é a mesma. Observador ou escutador dá na mesma. Assunto ou fonte...

Tem várias formas de fazer e obter o mesmo resultado, tudo aplica o padrão se atender alguns requisitos. Por isso que eu digo que *padrão* não deveria ser seguido como se fosse receita de bolo. Até é, mas tudo merece adaptação.

Há um acoplamento maior pelo exemplo mostrado. Mas não sei se é intencional para esse caso. O fato de haver acoplamento pode ter sido proposital para esse exemplo. É uma forma de exigir que o observador seja escrito de uma determinada forma pra poder assinar aquele evento. É mais comum deixar um nome padrão de método para tudo. Geralmente é escolhido `notify()`. Mas no fundo o acoplamento é o mínimo que tem que ser. Não sei se o nome vai afetar tanto, já que o método tem que saber o que fazer com aquele evento específico.

Mas isso chega ser até uma deficiência do Java antigo. Em linguagens que permitem ter funções passadas como parâmetros (quase todas as linguagens) o nome do método não importa, inclusive é passado um método anônimo.

O que o padrão exige:

- poder adicionar e retirar um método em uma lista de assinantes/escutadores;
- ter uma forma de avisar para toda a lista que uma determinada ação ocorreu;
- o observador precisa ter um método (assinante/escutador) capaz de receber as informações sobre quem o está notificando e qual o seu estado atual.

O "lista" foi por minha conta, que eu saiba não há nada que exija uma lista. Claro que uma lista é muito mais útil, sem ela, só poderia ter um assinante por vez e os demais falhariam tentando assinar (pelo menos assim espero em uma "boa implementação", se é que podemos chamar assim).

O resto é detalhe de implementação. Eu entendo que o que tem por aí é muito acadêmico e confunde, o padrão é mais simples do que parece.

Veja o [diagrama na Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). O exemplo de código já complica.

[image: Observer pattern]

Pra falar a verdade eu acho a forma do Java fazer isto muito confusa. Eu recomendo usar uma [forma mais simples com Java 8](https://dzone.com/articles/the-observer-pattern-using-modern-java) (esse exemplo é mais complicado do que deveria, mas é apenas o que eu achei).

Um [documento com uma visão interessante sobre este padrão](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/observer).

Só como um complemento, C# tem `event` que facilita ainda mais a criação do padrão. Esse mecanismo aliado ao `delegate` que é a base para a *lambda* e evento, foi o motivo do C# existir. A Sun não aceitou que a Microsoft colocasse isso no Java criando a [cisão para o J++, depois J# e C#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Java_Virtual_Machine).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: O exemplo com lambda começa tranquilo, depois ele começa a inserir um monte de coisa pra usar concorrencia kkk, mas deu pra entender.

Comment: É. Estou sem voto pra hoje, depois eu voto da pergunta.