# Como posso saber quais os objetos do ArrayList estão sendo modificados ou excluídos?

Tags: java, lista

Possuo um `ArrayList` que esta pré-carregado com alguns objetos do tipo da minha classe Pessoa, veja:

```
ArrayList<Pessoa> listaDePessoas = new ArrayList<>();
listaDePessoas.add(new Pessoa("Joao", 29));
listaDePessoas.add(new Pessoa("Ana", 21));
listaDePessoas.add(new Pessoa("Maria", 25));
```

Vamos supor que em um dado momento eu altero um desses objetos contido no `ArrayList` `listaDePessoas` veja:

```
listaDePessoas.get(0).setNome("Jao carlos");
```

E depois em um outro momento eu removo um desses objetos contido no `ArrayList` `listaDePessoas` veja abaixo:

```
listaDePessoas.remove(listaDePessoas.get(2));
```

Removi o objeto que esta na terceira posição da lista.

Estrutura da classe Pessoa:

```
public class Pessoa {    
    private String nome;
    public String getNome() { return nome; }
    public void setNome(String nome) { this.nome = nome; }
    private int idade;
    public int getIdade() { return idade; }
    public void setIdade(int idade) { this.idade = idade; }

    public Pessoa(String nome, int idade) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.idade = idade;
    }

    public Pessoa() { }
}
```

## Pergunta

Sendo assim, eu gostaria de saber como eu poderia saber quais objetos estão sendo modificados e quais estão sendo removidos da lista? Para que futuramente as modificações aplicadas nesses objetos (*alteração e exclusão*) sejam aplicadas em outro lugar.

Comment: Não sei se entendi que informação deseja obter da API.

Comment: Checar os modificados eu não faço ideia, mas os excluidos, me parece que o proprio ArrayList reordena o indice quando um item é removido. Veja a descrição do método [`remove()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28int%29): *Shifts any subsequent elements to the left (**subtracts one from their indices**).*

Comment: @diegofm não sabia que o método `remove(int index)` me retorna o elemento removido porem o método `remove(Object o)` retorna true se o elemento removido que foi especificado existir na lista.

Comment: @bigown preciso obter (uma copia dos objetos) os objetos que estão sendo removidos e alterados na lista.

Comment: Assim de repente a única possibilidade que eu encontro é ter uma classe que manipule o array e a criação/alteração dos objectos Pessoa. Tanto o array como os objectos serão privados dessa classe.

Comment: Não seria um caso de implementação do padrão observer, pra monitorar alterações?

Comment: @DenerCarvalho dá para postar a classe `Pessoa`? Posso estar enganado na sua necessidade, mas não parece ser o caso do `Observer`, pelo menos não com o que está na pergunta. Você precisa que outro objeto precise ser notificado que algo foi alterado nesse?

Comment: `Para que futuramente as modificações aplicadas nesses objetos (alteração e exclusão) sejam aplicadas em outro lugar.` Qual lugar? Pode dar detalhes?

Comment: @bigown vou editar aqui e colocar a classe `Pessoa`

Comment: @BrunoCosta as modificações serão aplicadas em um arquivo XML que contem vários objetos do tipo Pessoa.

Comment: @bigown sim preciso ser notificado, para aplicar as modificações em outro lugar.

Comment: @DenerCarvalho a pergunta ficou um bocadinho ampla :) Não que eu ache que precisa ser fechada. Você pode mudar essa classe `Pessoa`? Poderia implementar a interface `Clonable`?

Comment: @bigown se as mudanças ñ afetar muito a estrutura da classe ela ser mudada sim. A interface `Clonable` solucionaria? Eu até pensei em adicionar os objetos que estão sendo excluidos e alterados em outra lista `listaPessoasExcluidas` e `listaPessoasAlteradas` mas não sei se isso seria ideal :P

Comment: A `Clonable` é um dos passos, dá para fazer sem, mas complica bastante o uso. Como precisa ser observável, terá que por outras coisas de qualquer jeito, vai ficar "complicado", não tem jeito. Mas aí é que tá, sem saber o que precisa qualquer solução é errada, se vai criar uma lista, se vai notificar outra classe, se vai só retornar o objeto, tudo isso pede soluções diferentes. Um [mcve] em algo tão amplo e até não claro ajudaria muito. Está faltando requisitos certos para responder. Não fecho porque sei que você vai arrumar :)

Comment: @bigown eu poderia adicionar todo o contexto, porem isso ia fazer com que a pergunta ficasse ampla de mais e também muito difícil de testar o exemplo. Vou dar uma pesquisada na interface `Clonable` e ver o q eu encontro. Não tem problema nenhum a pergunta ser fechada, se a comunidade achar q ela deve ser fechada eu também votarei para fecha-la ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Resposta simplista

Não dá para fazer isto em Java.

## Resposta impraticável

Você poderia instrumentalizar as classes do Java de modo a interceptar os acessos e alterações realizadas nos objetos.

## Resposta razoável

Implemente um padrão de acesso aos objetos que permita reproduzir as ações realizadas.

Isso me lembra o [padrão arquitetural Event Sourcing](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html), onde as operações realizadas sobre os dados são armazenados como eventos, sendo possível então reproduzir, desfazer e navegar pelo histórico de eventos do sistema.

Toda alteração nos dados deve ser feita por uma classe que gerencia os dados e será representada por um objeto que contém os dados do evento.

## Exemplo

Fiz uma implementação simples baseado no código da pergunta:

### Classe `Pessoa`

Alterei para ser imutável, pois é uma boa prática.

```
public class Pessoa {
    private final String nome;
    private final int idade;

    public Pessoa(String nome, int idade) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.idade = idade;
    }

    public String getNome() { return nome; }
    public int getIdade() { return idade; }

    @Override
    public String toString() { return nome + " / " + idade; }
}
```

### Interface dos eventos

```
interface Event {
    void apply(List<Pessoa> lista);
}
```

### Evento para adicionar uma pessoa

```
public class AddPessoaEvent implements Event {
    private final Pessoa p;

    public AddPessoaEvent(Pessoa p) {
        this.p = p;
    }

    @Override
    public void apply(List<Pessoa> lista) {
        System.out.println("* Adicionando " + p);
        lista.add(p);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() { return "Add " + p.getNome(); }
}
```

### Evento apra remover uma pessoa

```
public class RemovePessoaEvent implements Event {
    private final int index;

    public RemovePessoaEvent(int index) {
        this.index = index;
    }

    @Override
    public void apply(List<Pessoa> lista) {
        System.out.println("* Removendo " + index);
        lista.remove(index);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() { return "Remove " + index; }
}
```

### Evento para atualizar o nome de uma pessoa

```
public class AtualizaNomePessoaEvent implements Event {
    private final int index;
    private final String nome;

    AtualizaNomePessoaEvent(int index, String nome) {
        this.index = index;
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    @Override
    public void apply(List<Pessoa> lista) {
        System.out.println("* Atualizando " + index + " com nome " + nome);
        lista.set(index, new Pessoa(nome, lista.get(index).idade));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Atualiza " + index + " com nome " + nome;
    }
}
```

### Classe gerenciadora da lista de pessoas

```
public class PessoasManager {
    private final List<Pessoa> listaDePessoas = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<Event> eventos = new ArrayList<>();

    public void add(Pessoa p) {
        AddPessoaEvent e = new AddPessoaEvent(p);
        eventos.add(e);
        e.apply(listaDePessoas);
    }

    public void remove(int index) {
        RemovePessoaEvent e = new RemovePessoaEvent(index);
        eventos.add(e);
        e.apply(listaDePessoas);
    }

    public void atualizaNome(int index, String nome) {
        AtualizaNomePessoaEvent e = new AtualizaNomePessoaEvent(index, nome);
        eventos.add(e);
        e.apply(listaDePessoas);
    }

    public List<Pessoa> getListaDePessoas() { return listaDePessoas; }
    public List<Event> getEventos() { return eventos; }

    public void replay(List<Event> eventos) {
        for (Event e : eventos) {
            this.eventos.add(e);
            e.apply(listaDePessoas);
        }
    }
}
```

### Usando as classes

O código principal para realizar as operações mencionadas na pergunta seria o seguinte:

```
PessoasManager pm = new PessoasManager();
pm.add(new Pessoa("Joao", 29));
pm.add(new Pessoa("Ana", 21));
pm.add(new Pessoa("Maria", 25));
pm.atualizaNome(0, "Jao Carlos");
pm.remove(2);
```

Cada método do gerenciador de pessoas cria o respectivo evento e o aplica na lista de pessoas. Como cada método `apply` tem um `println`, isto iria imprimir no console:

> - Adicionando Joao / 29
> - Adicionando Ana / 21
> - Adicionando Maria / 25
> - Atualizando 0 com nome Jao Carlos
> - Removendo 2

Imprimindo as listas de pessoas e eventos:

```
System.out.println("Pessoas " + pm.getListaDePessoas());
System.out.println("Eventos " + pm.getEventos());
```

Temos o resultado:

> Pessoas [Jao Carlos / 29, Ana / 21]
>
> Eventos [Add Joao, Add Ana, Add Maria, Atualiza 0 com nome Jao Carlos, Remove 2]

Então, como temos os eventos, podemos aplicá-los novamente em outra lista, criando outro gerenciador de pessoas e usando o método `replay`:

```
PessoasManager pm2 = new PessoasManager();
pm2.replay(pm.getEventos());
```

A segunda linha acima irá produzir a mesma exata saída no console referente, já que os mesmos eventos serão aplicados novamente. E se imprimir a nova lista de pessoas ela também vai ser a mesma que a anterior.

Algo interessante neste padrão, é que você poderia replicar os eventos em outra estrutura de dados criando outro método análogo ao `apply`. Ao invés de uma lista, poderia ser uma conexão com o banco, por exemplo.

## Desvantagens

O padrão, tal qual aplicado acima, pode gerar eventos desnecessários. Imagine um nome de uma pessoa atualizado diversas vezes.

Portanto, se o histórico não é importante para você, outra alternativa seria armazenar a lista inicial, criar uma cópia dela, aplicar as alterações e no final gerar um *diff*, ou seja, uma lista de diferenças entre o estado inicial e o final, de modo a executar o número mínimo de operações possível quando for aplicá-las em sua outra fonte de dados.

Outra alternativa mais simples, quando a lista é pequena e não há  dependências, é simplesmente não tentar replicar o processo, mas substituir os dados de destino pelos novos dados. Por exemplo, eu trabalhei num sistema, há alguns anos, onde o usuário podia editar uma tabela. Atualizar cada campo e registro no banco de acordo com a linha e coluna da tela era complicado, principalmente porque o usuário poderia incluir e excluir linhas e colunas arbitrariamente. Nesta situação específica, decidimos que a solução mais viável no momento era simplesmente apagar os registros existentes e recriá-los todos a partir dos novos valores.

Answer (score 4):

Já que você sabe qual é o objeto que deseja basta fazer uma cópia dele antes de fazer alguma operação. É uma técnica básica, não existe "mágica".

## Alteração

```
Pessoa pessoaAlterada = listaDePessoas.get(0).clone();
listaDePessoas.get(0).setNome("Jao carlos");
```

Não fiz uma cópia simples. Como o tipo é por referência a cópia seria da referência, portanto `pessoaAlterada` apontaria para o mesmo local da memória onde está objeto apontando o elemento na lista, então a alteração seria vista nessa cópia. A solução foi clonar o objeto. Por isso tive que implementar a interface `Cloneable` na classe. Até tem como fazer na mão, mas não é o ideal.

Com a clonagem a cópia apontará para um novo objeto com os mesmos dados do que será alterado em seguida. Por ser um objeto independente a alteração do objeto referenciado na lista não afetará o objeto clonado.

Só é importante entender que essa é uma clonagem rasa, então todos os bits do objeto serão copiados, inclusive as referências contidas nesses objeto. Concluímos que o objeto novo apontará para os mesmos objetos que o compõe que o objeto original está apontando. Se o objeto original mudar esses objetos de composição, o objeto clonado verá as alterações. Para evitar isso precisaria de uma clonagem profunda que clona toda a árvore de objetos, tornando tudo independente. Precisa ver se é o que deseja.

Se quer a clonagem profunda, ou o tipo de dado (`Pessoa`) deve ter um método  `clone()` que faça isso por você, ou terá que criar um algoritmo no código para fazer toda clonagem de toda a árvore na mão. Não fiz até porque não parece ser necessário nesse caso, mas poderia ser se colocar atributos novos. Mesmo a `String` que é um tipo por referência tem semântica de tipo por valor e é imutável, então não tem esse problema, uma alteração criaria um novo objeto.

Isso tipo de cópia é perigosa se não souber o que está fazendo.

Falo sobre cópia rasa e cópia profunda em [Cópia de classe em C#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156883/101). É muito parecido com o Java.

## Remoção

```
Pessoa pessoaRemovida = listaDePessoas.remove(2);
```

Perceba que não precisa pegar o objeto se já sabe o índice. E essa [sobrecarga do método](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove-int-) retorna o próprio objeto (a referência), então nem precisa fazer uma cópia anterior.

Para remover não precisa fazer cópia alguma do objeto em si, afinal você removeu ele da lista, então ele não será mais acessível na lista, então pode usar ele mesmo. Claro que se tiver algum outro motivo para clonar o objeto pode fazer também, igual ao exemplo anterior.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/uU3IEC). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/lgphwson-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Class/Clone.java).

## Notificação

Não está claro ainda se precisa ou não da notificação, é possível fazer isso na classe, mas precisaria ver como será consumido isso. Tem algumas perguntas sobre o assunto:

- [Como funciona e como implementar o Design Pattern Observer?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/36655/101)
- [Design pattern Observer aplicado em eventos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45020/101)
- [Listeners são uma implementação de Observer?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125624/101)
- [Observer pode ser considerado quebra de encapsulamento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/153015/101)

A ideia básica é colocar em `Pessoa` um *array*:

```
private List<Observer> observers = new ArrayList<Observer>();
```

Uma forma de assinar:

```
public void subscribe(Observer observer) {
    observers.add(observer);       
}
```

Os notificador:

```
public void notifyAllObservers() {
    for (Observer observer : observers) {
        observer.update(this);
    }
}
```

Quando a propriedade for modificada precisa disparar a notificação:

```
public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
    notifyAllObservers();
}
```

A interface `Observer` seria algo assim:

```
public interface ObserverPessoa {
    public void update(Pessoa pessoa);
}
```

E os consumidores seria algo assim:

```
public class Consumidor extends Observer {
    @Override
    public void update(Pessoa pessoa) {
        //faz o que quiser aqui 
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Class/Notification.java).

É uma ideia, tem várias outras de fazer. Essa eu fiz sem pensar muito, sem conhecer o caso real. Ela tem vantagens e desvantagens. Só postei para dar uma ideia, não quer dizer que eu faria isso.

Se precisa da notificação na lista precisa ver onde está a lista e montar algo semelhante ao acima nessa classe. Pode ter notificações gerais ou especializadas.