# O que é um evento?

Tags: terminologia, design-pattern, eventos

Muito se ouve falar em eventos:

- Disparar eventos;
- Programar eventos;
- Acionar eventos...

Apesar de muito se encontrar na internet, nenhum traz uma definição concreta do que realmente é um evento em programação. Então o que é um evento em programação, para que servem e onde são utilizados?

Comment: Segundo a [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_(computing)](Wikipedia), um evento é uma ação reconhecida pelo Software que pode ser manipulada. Apesar de eu entender (ou achar que entendo kkk) o que é um evento, não sou capaz de dar uma resposta completa, que essa resposta merece, então só deixo minha contribuição aqui :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> In computing, an event is an action or occurrence recognized by software that may be handled by the software

Então segundo a Wikipedia é uma ação ou ocorrência reconhecida pela aplicação que precisa ser manipulada por essa aplicação.

Sendo mais direto é um acontecimento, algo que mudou de estado, ou executou alguma coisa que deve determinar uma possível outra ação não relacionada diretamente. Um evento pode ser gerado pelo hardware ou algum componente de software, incluindo sua própria aplicação.

O evento, no contexto que parece perguntar, é todo o mecanismo que permite notificar outras áreas da aplicação que desejam saber que algo específico aconteceu.

## Exemplos

Um evento é uma tecla pressionada, um movimento de um mouse, um botão de um *joystick*, uma entrada de dados no microfone, *scanner*, rede, instalação de algum dispositivo, uma notificação ide um serviço, uma informação relevante do sistema operacional que precisa ser manipulada imediatamente, um acontecimento de uma API, como GUI, banco de dados, sistema de arquivos (um arquivo foi criado, modificado, apagado, acessado, etc.), ou serviço web, como o GitHub informar que houve um *commit*, ou ainda em sua aplicação onde a conta bancária precisa ser notificada quando um depósito for feito, ou um cliente faz uma compra maior que um valor. Tá cheio de exemplos nas outras perguntas *linkadas* aqui.

Todo sistema de GUI é um dos maiores exemplos. No Windows tudo o que ocorre que sua aplicação deva ficar sabendo é enviado uma mensagem para ela dizendo o que ocorreu para a aplicação decidir o que fazer. Isso é um evento, ainda que não costume levar esse nome, até por não adotar o paradigma específico.

Recentemente pegou moda servir HTTP por eventos (Nginx, Node.js são os mais conhecidos, mas quase todos os *stacks* fazem isso agora). A vantagem disto é que a aplicação não fica esperando algo acontecer, ela responde à necessidade quando o evento é disparado.

O evento é um mecanismo muito simples na verdade, mas com resultados poderosos. Isto pode ser visto com mais detalhes nos *links* abaixo.

Saiba mais sobre [programação orientada a eventos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80601/101).

Os eventos são uma forma de implementação do [padrão Observer](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/36655/101).

Sobre os [*event handlers*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/207569/101).

Veja também [Listeners são uma implementação de Observer?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/125624/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 3):

"Evento" normalmente é o mesmo que função ou procedure, ou seja, são blocos de códigos com objetivos especificos. O que ocorre é que o termo evento está mais relacionado a partes da aplicação que haverá iteração externa (humana ou não) disparando este evento.

Isso fica bem claro em aplicações que possui a construção de interfaces, como o visual basic, onde tem os componentes (botão por exemplo) e este botão possui o "evento" de "clique no botão".