# O que são e como funcionam sinais?

Tags: sistema-operacional, processo

Eles existem apenas no Unix ou também no Windows? Se sim, qual seria o equivalente no sistema Windows?

- Qual a relação com *signal handling*?
- Um exemplo prático de um *signal handling* pode ser qualquer linguagem apenas para demonstrar o conceito.
- Em quais casos é recomendado trabalhar com sinais na programação?

Comment: São um modo de IPC

Comment: Tem uma introdução [nessa minha resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/214199/64969) sobre o assunto. É superficial e voltado para comunicação entre processos, mas dá para iniciar

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sinais, assim aberto, pode ser muita coisa, mesmo em computação, ao que parece está falando mesmo do termo usado em sinalização de sistema operacional. Mas ele existe no *hardware* (ainda que geralmente chame de interrupção), ou em conceitos específicos ou [tecnologias em outro nível](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html). Não sei se tem tão claro a diferença de cada termo.

Conhece [eventos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/207571/101)? Evento é uma abstração em um nível pouco acima da sinalização. Portanto um sinal é uma informação que é passada para um algoritmo, geralmente interrompendo a execução normal de alguma forma para processar algo que quem recebe a sinalização define o que fazer.

O Linux faz isso sempre que ele precisa informar uma aplicação que algo do interesse dela aconteceu e ela deve processar aquilo. Em geral você pode escolher o que processar, e é comum precisar responder que você fez algo, ou que não fará, ou que o emissor do sinal deve continuar de alguma forma específica. O Linux pode não ser bem o emissor inicial, ele coordena a sinalização, mas uma outra aplicação pode soltar o sinal.

O Windows tem um mecanismo muito semelhante, mas não o chama de sinalização. E claro, os detalhes são diferentes. Há quem goste mais de um jeito ou do outro.

Eu não costumo fazer programação baixo nível em Linux por isso não posso dar muitos detalhes, mas sei que em um projeto futuro terei que ficar craque nisso, se sair do papel :) Eu uso mecanismo um pouco mais abstrato em linguagens de nível mais alto. Já fiz algumas coisas no Windows e a sinalização ocorre através de um [*callback*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27177/101) geralmente chamada [`WindowProc()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms633573(v=vs.85)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) ([tutorial](http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/)).

Talvez até por alguma compatibilização [o Windows é capaz de processar sinais iguais aos do Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/xdkz3x12(v%3Dvs.140)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), mas não sei bem o contexto.

A utilização vem sempre da necessidade de indicar para alguma aplicação, ou parte de uma, que algo aconteceu e precisa de uma posição do que fazer.

Uma [lista de sinais](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6332/1915).

Não tome esta como uma resposta canônica.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Maniero você consegue adicionar um exemplo básico para eu poder lhe dar a recompensa?

Comment: Vou tentar, o problema é que a pergunta é meio aberta, pode dar uma que nada ajuda.