# Dificuldade em chamada XMLHttpRequest com JavaScript puro

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, maps-javascript-api

Estou com dificuldade a uns dias, sou iniciante e mesmo lendo a documentação as vezes aplicar não é tão simples quanto parece, entendo que me falta exp para compreender.

meu problema: estou usando a api google maps JavaScript e uma API que eu fiz para carregar no mapa os pontos (marcadores). Porém, as vezes carrega o mapa e não carrega os pontos, consigo ver isso pois usei o `console.log(marcadores.length)` para verificar e ele vem zerado, aí eu atualizo a página e tudo carrega corretamente, mas também pode carregar vazio novamente.

Alguém poderia por favor me dar uma luz?

Eu gostaria de chamar a função `initMap()` somente após carregar o array com os dados que vieram da API do meu DB, como proceder?

Segue abaixo código que utilizo para carregar os dados da api:

```
var marcadores = [];
function carregaPosicoes(){
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "http://localhost:5000/Truck/Veiculos", true);
  
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        const data = JSON.parse(this.response);
        data.forEach(veiculo => {
            marcadores.push(veiculo);
            });
        };
    };
    initMap();
    request.send();

};
```

Comment: pode mover `initMap();` para dentro da function `onreadystatechange`. Aqui o conceito é quando executa a linha `request.open` o fluxo do código já segue para a linha a seguir que é  `request.onreadystatechange`, porém essa linha espera o retorna da API, uma *promise* como chamamos, então como ainda não há nada, segue para próxima linha que é o `initMap()` e ai ainda não tem dados, pq a chamada ainda não retornou, por isso precisa mover essa linha para dentro da function

Comment: Pelo o que eu entendi, voce poderia chamar a funcao `init` dentro do `if`, após o `forEach`. Testou dessa forma?

Comment: @RicardoPontual 4 segundos mais rápido do que eu XD

Comment: :D foi quase instantaneo @CmteCardeal, pra não perder a piada, eu fui mais "Pontual" ;)

Comment: A sua pergunta não tem relação com _async/await_. Tem mais haver com o objeto `XMLHttpRequest`, então eu editei o titulo da pergunta.

Comment: @RicardoPontual hahahahah [hahaha](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=il9CTqbvOcc). Pontuando que a pergunta tem mais haver com `XMLHttpRequest` do que async/await

Comment: @CmteCardeal, obrigado pela edição, é que quando eu pesquisava sobre "esperar carregar objeto e executar função" sempre caia em async/await. Vou testar as sugestões aqui e volto para comentar o que funcionou. muito obrigado a todos até o momento.

Comment: adicionei uma responsta para demontrar o que o @Piovezan respondeu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para complementar a resposta do @Piovezan, vou montar um exemplo simples demonstrando o fluxo do programa quando se tem um *callback* ou *promise*.

Esse pedaço de programa escreve no console os pontos por onde passa, 1 em 1. Repare que, ao executar a orden não é a mesma, porque foi criada uma *function* para gerar uma espera de 1s, e simula uma chamada assíncrona, por exemplo uma API:

```js
/////////////// 1
console.log("ponto 1");
var dados = {};

/////////////// 2
console.log("ponto 2");
sleep(1000).then(() => {
    /////////////// 3
    console.log("ponto 3");
    dados.algumaCoisa = "oi";
    
    /////////////// 4
    console.log("ponto 4");
    console.log("dados.algumaCoisa=" + dados.algumaCoisa);
});

/////////////// 5
console.log("ponto 5");
console.log("dados.algumaCoisa=" + dados.algumaCoisa);

function sleep (time) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
}

/////////////// 6
console.log("ponto 6");
```

O resultado desse código é:

```
ponto 1
ponto 2
ponto 5  <- aqui seguiu o fluxo, pulou os dois pontos que estão na função de callback
dados.algumaCoisa=undefined  <- algumaCoisa ainda não foi definido
ponto 6
ponto 3 <- após 1s, entra no callback
ponto 4
dados.algumaCoisa=oi <- agora algumaCoisa tem valor :)
```

Comment: Pelo pouco que entendo de JS, Promises são um conceito bem análogo a Futures do Java. Ambos retornam uma referência para algo que ainda não chegou a ocorrer, ter essa referência agora não é muito útil mas por outro lado é bastante útil poder usá-la para definir qual vai ser a callback que vai ser chamada após essa ocorrência (em geral para lidar com o resultado retornado pela ocorrência, como dados trazidos de uma requisição remota). É uma forma de programar reatividade a eventos. Mas acho que você deu uma pequena volta no exemplo, a callback poderia ter sido passada direto para setTimeout().

Comment: Mas sei que fez isso para ilustras as Promises, o resultado só fica mais complicado de entender (mas fica mais fácil quando você acompanha o código na ordem que os comentários indicam). :) A utilidade é demonstrada quando você observa que o código que reage ao evento está frequentemente vinculado ao momento em que esse evento é chamado, então apesar de ocorrerem em momentos distintos devem ficar juntos a fim de compartilharem o mesmo escopo.

Answer (score 2):

Entenda que essa `function()` abaixo é uma "callback" (você não manda chamar diretamente, só passa a referência da função para alguém que irá mandar chamá-la quando for o momento apropriado para isso) e está sendo declarada agora mas só irá ser chamada pelo objeto `XMLHttpRequest` quando ocorrer o evento ready state change, ou seja, num momento posterior a quando foi declarada (quando o sua requisição (request) para a API do servidor, que leva um tempo para ocorrer e o código não pode ficar esperando, tiver chegado ao fim, por exemplo), enquanto que a `initMap()` já está sendo chamada logo após essa declaração e antes da requisição ocorrer.

```
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        const data = JSON.parse(this.response);
        data.forEach(veiculo => {
            marcadores.push(veiculo);
            });
        };
    };
    initMap();
```

Tentando fazer um tradução, o nome "onreadystatechange" significa *"quando ocorrer a mudança no estado 'pronto', ou para o estado 'pronto' (me chame)"* e indica qual função vai ser chamada quando ocorrer esse evento. "on`<nome-do-evento>`" é uma nomenclatura comum para essa situação de código que reage a eventos.

Portanto jogando a `initMap()` para ser chamada dentro dela deve resolver, pois passará a chamar quando o evento ocorrer e logo após isso ter populado o mapa:

```
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        const data = JSON.parse(this.response);
        data.forEach(veiculo => {
            marcadores.push(veiculo);
            });
        };
       initMap();
    };
```

Para saber mais:

- [O que é um evento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/207571/357)
- [O que é callback?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27177/357)